# What software produces this pattern of redirect?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to activate HTTPS on my website but *something* is producing a redirect from HTTPS to a subdomain. Web guy says its the server. Server guy says its the app. I checked the vhost and httpd.conf and there is no redirect that matches. The application is Wordpress but there is no instance of the subdomain existing in the database or the source code.

Please take a look at the server response. Do you recognize what software produces this pattern of response?

```
$ curl -i https://www.example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 23 Jan 2018 17:06:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.1.11
Last-Modified: Tue, 13 Jun 2006 16:25:18 GMT
ETag: "9b-4161d83351780"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 155
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh"
      CONTENT="0; URL=http://somewhereelse.example.com">
<title> redirecting...
</title></head>
<body> </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is an HTML redirect, not HTTP, so it seems virtually certain to me that it's coming from the app, not the server.

Comment: That idea had occurred to me but the absence of `somewhereelse.example.com` in the DB or the source code seemed to point in the other direction.

Comment: it may added to: `header.php`, `functions.php` or hooked to some header action. which one you checked?